# Rust share variable accross async tokio tasks

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

I want to have 3 tasks running, where task 1 stops after every other task is finished. This should be achieved by having a mut u8 variable called `jobs_finished` which is incremented after a task has finished.

The following code represents what I want to achieve, but is just pseudocode because it is not working:

```
#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {

    let jobs_finished: u8 = 0;

    // vector of futures
    let futures = vec![
        tokio::spawn(async move {
            loop {
                tokio::time::sleep(std::time::Duration::from_secs(2)).await;
                println!("hello from tokio 1. Jobs allready finished: {}", jobs_finished);

                if jobs_finished >= 2 {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }),
        tokio::spawn(async move {
            println!("hello from tokio 2");
            jobs_finished += 1;
        }),
        tokio::spawn(async move{
            tokio::time::sleep(std::time::Duration::from_secs(8)).await;
            println!("hello from tokio 3.");
            jobs_finished += 1;
        }),
    ];

    // wait for all futures to complete
    for future in futures {
        future.await.unwrap();
    }
}
```

I tried using `Arc::new()` with a `Mutex` of an integer, but I can't use the same variable more than once due to `move`. Following example code was successful when used in two(?) tasks. I could increment in task 2 and read in task 1, but also incrementing in task 3 failed.

```
let data = Arc::clone(&jobs_finished);
data = data.lock().unwrap();
data = +1:
drop(data);
```

The main goal in my code is to simulate how a variable can be incremented/modified/read from multiple tasks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Arc<AtomicUsize>` to share a counter between tasks. Clone the `Arc` before passing them to closures.

The `u8` is a `Copy` type, which means each task captures the `jobs_finished` variable by copying its value, so they all see different values. That's why your code doesn't work.

```rust
#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let counter = Arc::new(AtomicUsize::new(0));

    let tasks = vec![
        {
            let counter = counter.clone();
            tokio::spawn(async move {
                tokio::time::sleep(Duration::from_secs(1)).await;
                println!("Task 1");
                counter.fetch_add(1, Ordering::SeqCst);
            })
        },
        {
            let counter = counter.clone();
            tokio::spawn(async move {
                tokio::time::sleep(Duration::from_secs(2)).await;
                println!("Task 2");
                counter.fetch_add(1, Ordering::SeqCst);
            })
        },
        {
            let counter = counter.clone();
            tokio::spawn(async move {
                while counter.load(Ordering::SeqCst) < 2 {
                    tokio::time::sleep(Duration::from_millis(100)).await;
                }
                println!("Finished.");
            })
        }
    ];

    futures::future::join_all(tasks).await;
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=fd37cea344650e221fa46d12205579b7)

As you asked `Arc<Mutex<u8>>` would work as well. But atomics are more efficient than mutexes.